# How can I determine whether I can use a name commercially?

Tags: copyright, trademark

Where can I search for whether I can or cannot use the name "Connect 4" or "Connect four" for my game?

Comment: Google it and check if the site in your country has Connect 4(tm)

Comment: my country? I'd like to put it in all mobile stores + additionally on website. So assume it counts where the server is, right? What about mobile stores?

Comment: You would need to check the laws of where ever you are selling it to.

Comment: @Terry seriously? Besides few countries like North Korea, AppStore works in every country.

Comment: I think you have made an assumption which isn't quite true. Some apps are only available in certain countries due to copyright/trademarks etc.. I'll find you a reference later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the United States [you can search trademarks at the U.S. Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO) website](http://www.uspto.gov/trademarks-application-process/search-trademark-database).

http://www.uspto.gov/trademarks-application-process/search-trademark-database

Comment: What about mobile stores? Should it be free in US Patent and Trademark Office? What about website, is it important where my host is registered?

Answer (score 1):

In the UK you can use the [Intellectual Property Office](https://www.gov.uk/search-for-trademark)'s website to search for trademarks.